# How to replace character in nginx variable?

Tags: nginx

I have a variable that has in it
`first_name_domain`

And I want to transform it in
`first.name.domain`

I have tried something like

```
if ($subdomain ~ ^(.+&|)(LAYERS=[^&]+)_(.*)$) {
    set $subdomain2 $1$2.$3;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to replace some character multiply times like you want to (except of using third party modules). As a workaround, to replace limited quantity of characters, you can try a chain of the `map` blocks:

```
map $layers $first_replacement {
    ~^(?<first_prefix>.*?)_(?<first_suffix>.*)$  $first_prefix.$second_replacement;
    default  $layers;
}
map $first_suffix $second_replacement {
    ~^(?<second_prefix>.*?)_(?<second_suffix>.*)$  $second_prefix.$third_replacement;
    default  $first_suffix;
}
map $second_suffix $third_replacement {
    ~^(?<third_prefix>.*?)_(?<third_suffix>.*)$  $third_prefix.$third_suffix;
    default  $second_suffix;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($subdomain ~ ^(?<prefix>.+&|)(?<fixed>LAYERS=[^&]*?)_(?<layers>[^&]*)(?<suffix>&.*|$) {
        set $subdomain2 $prefix$fixed.$first_replacement$suffix;
    }
    ...
}
```

This example will replace maximum of four underscores, but you can increase the number of `map` blocks if you need.